# Как отправлять данные без нажатия кнопки submit?

Tags: php, laravel, form, submit

Как сделать, чтобы при заполнении полей формы данные отпралялись сразу в базу без нажатия кнопки submit?

Comment: Не советую так делать. Отправка по ajax - ок, но отправка сразу же при заполнении - не ок..... т.к. пользователь может опечататься, ошибиться и шанса на исправление не будет.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в некоторых случаях (например ввод кода подтверждения) это очень удобно. Естественно надо оставить возможность исправить опечатку.

Comment: @Valc Kon уточните, что вы хотите сделать? Если вы ещё не знаете, что браузер может отправлять запросы с данными вообще в любое время и без нажатия кнопок, то возможно вам надо загуглить "ajax". Если вы умеете отправлять запросы из браузера, но хотели бы реализовать что-то необычное (например, автосохранение при редактировании), то уточните свой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вешай ajax запрос на обработчик onblur. Ни в коем случае нельзя делать постоянное изменение записи на oninput или onchange(тут правда есть исключения, например с select всё корректно). В таком случае при окончательном вводе вы просто убираете фокус(например по нажатию Tab) с поля и оно сохраняется в базу.
выглядеть будет примерно так

```
<input type="text" onblur="ajax()" id="nameF">
```

А вообще зависит от типа полей которые нужно отправлять и сколько их в форме. Если в каждом поле нужно вводить по одному символу, то вполне можно и на oninput вешать обработчик, а если в форме есть поле даты например, то тут пока полностью не будет введена дата, её нельзя записывать, иначе вы получите ошибку с некорректной датой.

Comment: onblur срабатывает даже если пользователь не менял значение инпута. Если поле последнее (единственное) в форме, то пользователю надо переключить куда-то фокус, что неочевидно.

Comment: В таком случае нужно делать запись по таймауту и запись поля в базу делать если оно было не пустым на момент проверки. Что-то вроде запуска функции с таймером на 5 секунд при вводе в поле(oninput), если ввод в этом поле начался снова, то обнуляем таймер и запускаем только когда ввод прекратился. Посл записи делать пометку о сохранении в виде галочки или подсветки например зелёным, чтоб хоть какая та индикация работы была.

Comment: @Егор Банин,  при заполении формы автоматически обновлять данные в базе